# Inputting a string won't output correctly (into a char variable)

Tags: c++

I'm writing a Caesar cipher encoder/decoder. I'm following specific guidelines including having the choice to encode or decode. The variable for encoding or decoding has to be a char and can be input as either "e", "d", "E", "D" or "Encode" "Decode". Anything that starts with "e, E" or "d, D" is acceptable.

Inputting the string "Encode" will not allow anymore input in my code. Entering the single character works.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int shift = 0;
    char inChoice;
    cout << "Do you wish to encode or decode?" << endl;
    cout << "(Type \"e\" to encode, or \"d\" to decode): ";
    cin >> inChoice;

    if (inChoice == 'e' || inChoice == 'E')
    {
        cout << "How many characters to shift?" << endl;
        cout << "(Enter a positive integer): ";
        cin >> shift;
        while (shift < 0){
            cout << "You must enter a positive integer: ";
            cin >> shift;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "You must either enter \"e\" or \"d\": ";
        cin >> inChoice;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The output will return as if I entered "e" into the input stream when prompted for if I wish to encode or decode. Then it will ask the key to shift and then not allow any further input and just stop the program.

Answer (score 0):

`inChoice` is a `char`, so when you read the user input it will only take the first character. If the user entered `Encode` then `inChoice` will contain `'E'` but the rest of the input is still waiting to be read. When you then get the input for `shift`, `cin` will see where the last input ended and try to turn `ncode` into an integer.

```cpp
    cin >> shift;  // looks at the end of the last input: "ncode"
```

Try reading the choice into a `string` instead of a `char` and look at the first character:

```cpp
    // ...
    std::string inChoice;
    cout << "Do you wish to encode or decode?" << endl;
    cout << "(Type \"e\" to encode, or \"d\" to decode): ";
    cin >> inChoice;

    if (inChoice[0] == 'e' || inChoice[0] == 'E')
    {
        // ...
```

Comment: Perfect, that's what I needed. This works inside of my program perfectly. I assume that the [0] means that it's only reading the first character? Which is exactly what the specifications require. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You need to  declare `inChoice` as a `std::string` rather than a `char`, because that's what is coming into your program from the standard input (a string of characters).